# Get host's hostname in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hostname

what is the equivalent of docker swarm's {{.Node.Hostname}} in docker-compose. I am trying to get host's hostname in my docker-compose.yml file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [extra_hosts option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts) of docker compose.

first you need to define an alias for your host machine loopback **in your host machine**. for example :

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.100.100.1/24
```

then **in your docker-compose** file:

```
extra_hosts:
    - "my_hostname:10.200.10.1"
```

to check the result run this :

```
$ docker exec -it your_container_name /bin/bash
// run a command to check connectivity to your host machine.like this:
// supposed you have a website running on host machine 
$ wget my_hostname/index.html
$ cat index.html
```